# How to install C9 on Ubuntu

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have seen several posts regarding Cloud9 and installing a local version.  I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and have managed to get Cloud9 up but can not get the Runner: PHP Builit-in Web Server to launch properly.  I get the error "https://undefined/workspace/file.php" and Invalid address error.  I would expect the URL to be more like https://my.ip.address/workspace/file.php

What is missing here that the Runner is not launching properly?

Comment: Can you set the $C9_HOSTNAME environment variable and run it again to see if that works?

Comment: Thanks, I assume you mean to set this in the IDE as part of the ENV?  This had no affect.  I also tried doing an export within the terminal to set the value and no affect.  The PHP (cli) runner operates just fine.

Comment: If I may ask a newbie question...  When I execute the runner "PHP Bulit-in Web Server" what is it using as the default port and default document directory?  I assume it is using the workspace directory for default directory but on a standalone configuration how can I manipulate this "built-in web server" configuraiton?